# Can class instances be accessed via an index in python?

Tags: python, oop, indexing

Consider for example that we have a class 'Agent' as below:

```
class Agent:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.position = [] 
        self.number = number         
        for i in range(number):
             self.position.append([0, 0])
```

I can make an instance of the class by:

```
agent = Agent(10)
```

and then access the i'th agent's position by:

```
agent.position[i]
```

However, this does not seem elegant enough and to me it's a bit counter-intuitive. Instead I want to index the class instance itself. For example:

```
pos_i = agent[i].position
```

which should return the same answer as the one-line code above. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: But `position` is a list of the history of the positions?

Comment: Firthermore what you say is incorrect. You do not access the *i*-th agent's position, you access the agent's *i*-th position.

Comment: So is it possible to make i instances of the agent or is that redundant? The whole point is to be able to change those positions through some function. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: But here you attach a list of *positions* to *one* agent.

Comment: Hmm my goal here is to be able to change the positions of a class instance that otherwise have the same attributes. So my initial code is sufficient for this task, right? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Just as a coincidence, another person asked for a feature close to this today, using metaclasses. My answer there would enable you to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459016/how-to-create-a-metaclass-that-can-give-a-class-an-array-of-instances-and-provid/47460810#47460810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that, you just need a class-level container, with all instances.

Since your positions, given your example, are created in an arbitrary order, I'd suggest using a dictionary.

You can just fill the class-level "position" dictionary. You could then just implement the `__getitem__` method to retrieve elements from this dictionary:

```
class Agent:
   position = {}
   def __new__(cls, pos):
       if pos in cls.position:
           return cls.position[pos]
       instance = super().__new__(cls)
       cls.position[pos] = instance
       return instance

   def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.position[pos]
```

This, however, will only allow you to retrieve an instance given the position from an instance - i.e.:

```
agent_5 = Agent(5)
agent_10 = agent_5[10]
```

would work, but not:

```
agent_10 = Agent[10]
```

If you want that, you have to use a custom metaclass, and put the `__getitem__` method there:

```
class MAgent(type):
   def __getitem__(cls, item):
        return cls.position[pos]


class Agent(metaclass=MAgent):
   position = {}
   def __new__(cls, pos):
       if pos in cls.position:
           return cls.position[pos]
       instance = super().__new__(cls)
       cls.position[pos] = instance
       return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overload the indexing operator just overload the `__getitem__` method in the class.

```
class Agent:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.position[key]

>>> myobj = MyClass()
>>> myobj[3]
```